# paramiko stdout show nothing with regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, output, paramiko

I try to use paramiko to list all TCP ports used on a compute. I found a good bash command [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/14429/how-do-i-find-out-whether-a-port-is-available-on-ubuntu-8-04):

```
netstat -ant | sed -e '/^tcp/ !d' -e 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *.*[\.:]\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1/' | sort -g | uniq
```

This command works perfectly when I directly enter it in putty. However, when use it with paramiko, no output is shown.

Here is the sample code:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username='demo', password='password')
command = "netstat -ant | sed -e '/^tcp/ !d' -e 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *.*[\.:]\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1/' | sort -g | uniq"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
print stdout.read()
```

If I change the command as follow, the stdout do show the result, but this is not what I want. So I guess this is probably a regular expression issue with paramiko. Any idea?

```
command = "netstat -ant | sed -e '/^tcp/ !d'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\1'` is same as `'\x01'`. You should escape `\1`.

```
>>> '\1'
'\x01'
>>> print '\1'

>>> '\\1'
'\\1'
>>> print '\\1'
\1
>>> r'\1'
'\\1'
>>> print r'\1'
\1
```

Using raw string(`r'...'`) solve your problem:

```
command = r"netstat -ant | sed -e '/^tcp/ !d' -e 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *.*[\.:]\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1/' | sort -g | uniq"
```